# Import, rename, and merge Excel sheet in Python using loop

Tags: python, excel

I'm trying to import an Excel document into Python containing data spread out 100 sheets - I also have to repeat this process with dozens of Excel files.  My goal is to merge every other sheet into a different dataframe based on the variable `date`, which is present in each sheet, such as `dfx = pd.merge(df1, df3, on="date")`.

Each sheet, however, has an arbitrary/random name, so I'm trying to rename all the sheets in order 1 - 100, and then merge sheets 1 and 3, 2 and 4, etc.

I'm green at Python loops and programming generally, and am wondering how this can be accomplished?  Below is the first attempt that I took at the code, which returned the error `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`.  I haven't been able to figure out the merge element of the loop, either.

Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd

path = 'C:\\Python Structures'
xl = 'sample.xlsx'

xl = os.path.join(path, xl)


dfxl = pd.read_excel(xl)
xl_file = pd.ExcelFile(xl)

num_sheets = len(xl_file.sheet_names)

for i in num_sheets:
    df.i = xl_file.parse(i)
```

Comment: `num_sheets` is not iterator. is `int` value. [hope this helps](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp)

Comment: Thank you @DanilaGanchar, I appreciate it.  Would replacing it with something like xl_file.items() be more appropriate?

Comment: sorry but I didn't work with `pandas`. I guess that `xl_file.sheet_names` is iterator in your case. you can check it like this: `for i in xl_file.sheet_names: print(i)`